# How to set formula "=''Sheet Name''!B10" with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

The idea is to set dynamic value from sheet a to sheet b, where sheet b new value changes with the change in sheet a value.

Here I have defined all the ways that can be used to set value from sheet a to sheet b, but all this methods are not dynamically updating.

```
$ba = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->getCell('B10')->getCalculatedValue();

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B12', $ba);
```

Is the code I am using which is accurate but it sets the calculated value of B10 which is equal to "=SUM(B4:B5)" which gives a value 'X' and print 'X' on excel sheet.

If I use

```
$ba = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->getCell('B10')->getValue();
```

"not getCalculatedValue()"

In this case it will create a formula `'=SUM(B4:B5)'` and generate sum of B4 TO B5 values but from the same sheet not from the sheet from where I want to fetch.

Actual formula for that is `='sheet name'!B10`

But when I use this as

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B12', '=''Fixed Cost''!B10');
```

This will generate an error.

Comment: I want to upvote @vcsjones just for the edit.

Answer (score 11):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B12', "='Fixed Cost'!B10");
```

Comment: Straight from the horse's mouth. Excellent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry i saw it today as client REVERT back me again :) as he was convinced that "PHP to formulated excel conversion was impossible" :) and i make it working

Comment: @truthblue82 Then you've done something wrong.... but simply posting such a comment against somebody else's 5-year-old question is not how StackOverfow works... ask a proper question, posting a minimal example of what your'e actually doing, what you expect, and what you actually get

Comment: My code here:
$xfile = new PHPExcel();
$xfile->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet1 = $xfile->getActiveSheet();
$sheet1->setTitle('Sheet 1');
$sheet1->setCellValue('A1',100);
$xfile->createSheet();
$sheet2 = $xfile->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$sheet2->setCellValue('A1',"='Sheet 1'!A1");
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($xfile,'Excel2007');
$writer->save("php://output");
Header("Content-type: application/octet-stream; name=test.xlsx");
Header("Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

Could you help me?

Comment: Ask the question "AS A PROPER QUESTION"..... simply posting comments against somebofdy else's question is NOT asking a question. I WILL NOT HELP unless you ask your question properly!

Comment: PS. Sending the headers ___after___ saving the fie to the browser is simply wrong!!! That is not how http and the web work.... headers first, then content

Comment: @Mark Baker Thanks for your advice!